# Is there a CD/DVD disk reading test tool for Linux?

Tags: dvd, recording, testing, data-cd

When I was using DOS and Windows I've seen quite a selection of tools to check optical disks for readability and benchmark an optical drive itself. Most of them were even visualising the results in form of a pretty chart.

Are there any such for GNU/Linux OSes?

I'd prefer to have a full-featured visual GUI tool, but for the particular case I've got now, I just need to check if my CD drive can read every byte of a particular heavily-scratched CD-RW disk.

Answer (score 8):

To simply see if a drive can be read, you can use [dd(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd). This will read in the contents of the CDROM and will ignore/discard the data (note that the CDROM device may have another name on your system):

```
 dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/dev/null
```

It is also possible to compare this to an ISO image:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom | md5sum - /path/to/file.iso
```

This will print a checksum for the CD and for the ISO file. If the checksums match, the CD contents match the ISO image.

Comment: k3b is a graphical CD burning utility with built-in image verification and other neat features.

Comment: There's no need for `dd` here. `cat /dev/cdrom` and `md5sum /dev/cdrom /path/to/file.iso` will work just as well.

Comment: 'cat /dev/cdrom' might work, but you then have to pipe the output via your shell to discard it. I don't think this is really a better solution than using dd which is entirely self-contained. Using 'dd' will also provide errors, statistics, and other useful information that 'cat' will not.

Comment: You're right that md5sum can do the comparison on the file itself. For simple comparisons, it can be a better solution. However, it can be useful to throw 'pv' in the middle there, or to script around 'kill -USR1' to provide statistics. Remember that we're talking about relatively slow media such as CDs/DVDs. Besides, as silly of a reason as it might be, using 'dd' provided symmetry to the other example.

Comment: When running `md5sum` on either the image from the CD or that on the hard disk one should consider the possibility of having trailing zeroes at the end of the .iso file. See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39467/how-to-verify-a-cd-against-an-iso-image/47821#47821) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

For a low-level check, I found [qpxtool](http://qpxtool.sourceforge.net/). With my drive (which, to be fair, is not on the supported devices list), the results didn't make sense, but maybe you will have better luck.

Answer (score 4):

Command-line, there are `readom` (from cdrkit, a fork of cdrtools) and `readcd` (from Joerg Schilling's original cdrtools). Both can check for C2 errors.

There is also `cdck`, which will generate a text file that can be fed to gnuplot to get graphs.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [dvdisaster](http://dvdisaster.net/en/) to help me recover data from a few DVD and CD-R coasters I burned. It's a GTK application, and probably available as a package on your favorite Linux distribution.

It has a nice graphical display showing which sectors are good and bad. It also keeps various statistics while reading your media.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the command-line `GDDRescue` (GNU Data Rescue) which seems to be very flexible.

This [review](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/29355.aspx) of several tools for recovering data from scratched CD/DVDs, including `GDDRescue`. I had much better experience with `GDDRescue` than with `readcd`: using mainly default configs, `readcd` stumbled on a badly scratched DVD;  while `ddrescue` after some 72h of work nicely outputted a shiny `.iso` in which the read errors were minimized. As its man page states, `ddrescue` "tr[ied] hard to rescue data in case of read errors" and succeeded.